# Magento - Importing Configurable Products

Tags: magento

Can anyone provide some example csv on the basis of following instructions be magento to import configurable product?
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/importing-configurable-products

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use magmi.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/

It is a separate application. So, you will need to upload magmi folder under main magento folder.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Magmi or some other plugins for this purpose. (Magmi is free)
[Magmi](http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/)

For Magmi you can find the sample import sheet format on Magmi wiki

Comment: I could not find any installation guide. Can you tell me how to install magmi?

Answer (score -1):

You can use Magmi as the mass product up loader. Because Magento default product uploader is not good for mass upload and giving a hard time

http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/

Comment: How to install magmi?

Comment: You can download the Magmi from the soruceforge and copy the file in to your root. then go to this url -> www.yourdomain.com/magmi/web/magmi.php

with that page you can add your database details and upload the file and import :)